# Magnitude of complex function

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I was going through an example in a book and and it says to take the magnitude of the function. What it shows is

$$X(\omega)=\frac 1{\alpha+j\omega} \implies |X(\omega)|=\frac 1{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$$

I thought if you were to take the magnitude using $|X(\omega)| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

the result would come out to be something like this.

$$|X(\omega)|=\frac 1{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\omega^2}}$$

I think I am not understanding how to calculate the magnitude of a complex function.

--The entire question was

Calculate the energy of $X(t) = e^(-at)u[t]$  Via FT

$$X(\omega) =\frac 1{a+j\omega} \implies |X(\omega)|=\frac 1{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$$

$$E = \frac 1{2\pi}\int\frac 1{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$$ Some integral math $= \frac 1{2a}$

I understand how the integral is solved and all, I just don't understand the part where they took the magnitude.

Comment: Do we have $j^2=-1$ and $a, \omega \in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: a,ω∈R is true and of what I learned is j^2=−1

Comment: Then I don't understand why the book says what it does, can you give the book and the page reference?

Comment: I don't own the book. I will edit my main question with the example I wrote down from class. Give me a second and I'll have the entire problem up.

Comment: You are correct, but maybe the book says $\left |(X(\omega))\right |^2=\frac{1}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$?

Comment: I edited my question, and I just found the solution.... When calculating Energy it the magnitude squared..... So they just applied that early.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the function is correct here is why:
$$X(w) = \frac{1}{a+jw} = \frac{1}{a+jw}*\frac{a-jw}{a-jw} = \frac{a-jw}{a^2+w^2}$$
$$X(w) = \frac{a}{a^2+w^2}+ j*\frac{-w}{a^2+w^2}$$
$$|X(w)| = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{(a^2+w^2)^2} + \frac{w^2}{(a^2+w^2)^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2+w^2}}$$
$$|X(w)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+w^2}}$$